# YamlDotNet linter validation when importing

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, lint, yamldotnet

I am importing a yaml file from my system directory. I want to validate for linter issues before Deserializing the yaml. Is there any nuget which i can use to perform the lint validation??

Does [YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet) provide a lint validator

Comment: What do you expect from a YAML linter? Syntactic and structural errors will be discovered and reported during deserialization anyway. Are you after cosmetic problems?

Comment: yes i need to validate the cosmetic problems.